# How to remove GitHub commit along with it's history?

Tags: git, github, version-control

My friend made a config file, holding our apikey/token/secrets, and a `.gitignore` to ignore said file. Someone accidentally pushed to the master branch with the config file saved as another name and is now showing.

I was wondering if there was a way to delete that commit and the history of that commit.

I have seen this (below) and I understand this will **delete** the commit and re-push everything. **But** it still shows the config info via history/changes:

```
git reset --hard hash# 

git push -f origin branch
```

Comment: GitHub Help pages has something about exactly this case (private information pushed to GitHub)... I would transform it into an answer but I am on mobile at the moment [see here...](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)

Comment: @MischaBehrend THANKS! I guess I wasn't searching with the right keywords in google haha - thats a very useful page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) can help you in your case, as follows:

Replace `PATH-TO-YOUR-CONFIG-FILE` with the path to your config file you want to remove, not just its filename.

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-CONFIG-FILE' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Add your config file to `.gitignore` to ensure that you don't accidentally commit it again, commit and push it, following below commands:

```
echo "YOUR-CONFIG-FILE" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Add YOUR-CONFIG-FILE to .gitignore"
git push origin --force --all
```

Comment: Beware that this (like all history rewriting) changes commit hashes. That can be a major problem, especially when you're working with others. Furthermore, removing your credentials from history is not enough. They _must_ be invalidated and recreated. This reduces the value of a rewrite. Please be careful.